# What are the precise uses of Stone Shape?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

A. Can I touch a stone cavern side wall, and make a perpendicular stone shape protrude from it?

B. Can I touch a ton ceiling, shape a cube from it, that will therefore fall?

D. Can I shape it in this way : I touch a ceiling, take a cube of it and transform it's volume in a longer, thinner cylindric form, to make a column?

E. Can I touch the side wall of a tunnel, make a door with some thing that prevent it from moving int he ground right next to it, and open it, therefore closing the tunnel?

According to SRD :

> STONE SHAPE
>
> School transmutation [earth]; Level cleric 3, druid 3, sorcerer/wizard
>   4
>
> Casting Time 1 standard action
>
> Components V, S, M/DF (soft clay)
>
> Range touch
>
> Target stone or stone object touched, up to 10 cu. ft. + 1 cu.
>   ft./level
>
> Duration instantaneous
>
> Saving Throw none; Spell Resistance no
>
> You **can form an existing piece of stone into any shape that suits your
>   purpose**. While it's possible to make crude coffers, doors, and so
>   forth with stone shape, fine detail isn't possible. There is a 30%
>   chance that any shape including moving parts simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Answers:**

- A: Yes
- B: Depending on your level, it may not weigh a ton (But close enough), but yes
- D: Yes on changing the volume, be prepared for some geometry if the DM wants specifics
- E: Yes, but be careful about the failure chance on moving parts

As long as you follow the restrictions that the stone (and note that this spell only affects stone, not just earth. Your DM may specify that all of the stone must be connected, or that you can pull as much stone out in the volume the spell specifies) you're affecting is within reach, fine detail is not possible, and there is a high likelihood that moving parts will fail, you can reshape any body of stone into any other 3-Dimensional object, so long as you follow the volume requirements of your caster level.

If your DM is asking for specifics, then be ready for some [geometry](http://www.math.com/tables/geometry/volumes.htm). (A cylinder will be a circle x Height). This does include reshaping stone into a barrier for a tunnel, separating it from a wall or ceiling, or making a new entry into another space. You're also right that you can't just make it disappear; you have to move it to another place if you're just looking to get it out of your way.

Comment: I would argue that they really only need to change the surface area of the cube and not the volume, so getting a tone should be possible and even easy. So surface area of shapes instead of volume of shapes.