# Stone Shape Uses

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, kineticist

Specifically the Stone Sculptor Wild Talent for Earth Kineticists.
Can you create tunnels, or burrow with the stone shape spell? It says you may form stone into a shape that suits your purpose, but can you shape it into a tunnel to descend into the ground? Also, when you do this, is the stone you move displaced somewhere else?

Comment: A little over a week ago [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122314/8610) about the spell *stone shape* was posed. It may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The spell [***stone shape***](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stone-shape) (and, by extension, the kineticist [utility wild talent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/utility-wild-talents/) stone sculptor special ability) *can* be used to create tunnels through stone. Being able to shape stone, though, isn't the same as having a burrow speed. If a creature uses an effect like *shape stone* to create a tunnel, after that tunnel's created the creature must then traverse that tunnel using its available movement modes normally. (That is, the creature may have to climb down a newly created shaft like everyone else, although its walls could be shaped so as to have handholds that make the climb is easier.) A *stone shape* effect does *not*, for example, allow stone surfing *à la* the Marvel Comics mutant [Iceman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceman_(Marvel_Comics)):

[image: Put on some pants!] <sup>***…but with stone (so more like [Terrax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrax))***</sup>

Also, the *stone shape* spell only says it *shapes* the affected stone and doesn't say anything about, for example, *dissipating* unwanted stone or whatever, so the excess stone *must* go somewhere.

(Whether the spell *stone shape* can shape stone to such a degree that the stone is compressed into a smaller and far denser unit or even shaped into dust so that it can be easily dispersed is a question for the GM, but this GM would likely say no. The *stone shape* spell is typically only a 3rd-level spell, after all, and there are other spells that [shrink material](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shrink-item/), [annihilate material](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/disintegrate/), or [make neat holes in walls](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/passwall/).)